# Two optimization problems aligned horizontally one next to the other

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

As the title suggests. Below I'm attaching an example/image that helps visualize what I'm trying to do.

[image]

So far, I have been able to align my two optimization problems vertically. Searching other questions/answers here, I tried using the `multicol` package but the end result is really bad (see below for the code). I cannot figure out a nice alignment.

Any hints (packages or environments) that I could use to produce the alignment as shown in the picture?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{alignat}{3}
& \text{minimize} \quad && c ^ T x \\
& \text{subject to} \quad && A x = b, \\
& && x \succeq 0.
\end{alignat}\break

\begin{alignat}{2}
& \text{maximize} \quad && - b ^ T \nu \\
& \text{subject to} \quad && A ^ T \nu + c \succeq 0.
\end{alignat}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot you posted suggests that you want to *top-align* the two optimization problem statements. The `multicol` package may not be the best-suited tool for this typesetting objective. I would like to suggest that you use two side-by-side top-aligned `minipage` environments, each of width `0.45\textwidth`. A separate comment: since there really is just one alignment column in the optimization problem statements, `align` should do just as well as `alignat`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} for 'align' environment
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{align}
\text{minimize}   \quad& c ^ T\! x \\
\text{subject to} \quad& A x = b, \\
                       &x \succeq 0\,.
\end{align}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize separation between the 'minipage' environments
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{align}
\text{maximize}   \quad& - b ^ T\! \nu \\
\text{subject to} \quad& A ^ T\! \nu + c \succeq 0 \,.
\end{align}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```